# If the k of a wave is negative, is the wavelength negative too?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

My friend went to an interview for a reputed scholarship program and was asked this question.
A wave has an equation $a\sin(\omega t-kx)$.
Sometimes k surely can become -ve. 
We know that $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$.
 So $\lambda$ is -ve?
How can this be?

What he said was that we can write $k=\frac{\omega}{v}$.
Since $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{t}$, and t can't be -ve, v should be -ve.
So it implies that the wave is in -ve x direction.
That is why wavelength has come -ve due to this sign convention.
But they didn't agree to it.
Even I think the above is correct.
Where is the problem then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your equation for the wave is really a vector equation:

$$ \psi({\bf x}, t) = a \sin(\omega t - {\bf k . x}) $$

This tends to be glossed over when students are first taught the equation, and to be fair in 1D the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) $\bf k.x$ is simply $kx$ or $-kx$ depending on whether $\bf k$ and $\bf x$ point in the same or opposite directions.

Anyhow, $\bf k$ is the [wave vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector) and like all vectors has direction and magnitude. Its magnitude is the [wave number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber) $k$, and the wave number is equal to $2\pi/\lambda$. Because $k$ is the magnitude of a vector it is always positive, and therefore $\lambda$ is always positive.

When you have a wave travelling in the $-x$ direction it's not $\lambda$ that changes sign, it's the direction of $\bf k$.

Comment: Thanks for telling that, we were not actually taught this, but you mean that if k is -ve, then $\lambda$ is positive (no matter what)? And -ve k is just the direction of k?

Comment: @Rohinb97: Basically yes, the wavenumber $k$ is always positive. Writing $\omega t - kx$ (NB the non-vector form) means the wavevector points in the positive $x$ direction, while Writing $\omega t + kx$ means the wavevector points in the negative $x$ direction. But note that the wavenumber is positive in both cases. It seems confusing, but it's a result of trying to (over)simplify the vector form of the equation. While vectors are conceptually harder this confusion goes away iof you just use the vector form.

Comment: So, the above, which my friend said, that $k=\frac{\omega}{v}$, so v is -ve , and that's why $\lambda$ is -ve due to sign convention is wrong?